# Why do I get an error message saying Module Not Found: No module named ‘pyvo’ when I run ‘import pyvo as VO’?

Tags: import, module

[I keep getting the error message shown in the picture. I’m using the Carnets app on my iPad. BTW I’m totally new to coding and stackoverflow so I’m not familiar with a lot of syntax and stuff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mX71.jpg)

```
import pyvo as vo
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
%matplotlib inline


tap = vo.dal.TAPService("https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/TAP") # initialize TAP service

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [9], line 1
----> 1 import pyvo as vo
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyvo'
```

TBH I don’t even know where to start to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps pyvo is not installed in your system. try isntalling it with pip in your terminal

```
pip install pyvo
```

This might clear the issue you are facing

If you want to directly install it from the jupyter-notebook then in the cell you can write the following and run it.

```
!pip install pyvo
```

Do not forget to restart the kernal after the installation.

Comment: You should be recommending `%pip install pyvo` and not the use of the an exclamation point in conjunction with `pip` or `conda` install commands. In 2019, the magic install commands were added to insure the installations done inside the notebook occur in the environment where the kernel is running. That is current best practice in modern Jupyter. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the magic install commands. ...

Comment: <continued> [The second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues. That being the case lead to the addition of the magic install commands to overcome that in a convenient way. They work in modern Jupyter, even JupyterLite and Google Colab now. And you can use it as a gauge for how current advice is. If the advice suggest use of the exclamation point with install commands, take it with a grain of salt as it is outdated.